# How do I keep my lockscreen from turning off on my S3?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, lock-screens

I want to keep my lockscreen on longer than the few seconds it does now by default.  I don't see any settings to change this in the menus.  Is there a way to keep it on for 10 minutes or even permanently?

OS: 4.1
Phone: S3

Answer (score 2):

i guess what you are trying to say is that you want the screen to stay for a longer period of time after getting locked.

If that's the query then it has a very simple answer.

Simply go to settings>display. Now there you must see something like 'Screen timeout'. Just tap on that and choose the time you want to keep the screen awake.

Now it'll also keep the home screen awake for the selected time. This is because there are no settings for changing the screen timeouts differently for home and lock screens.

What you can do now is simply press the lock screen button at the top right. Once the screen gets locked press it again such that the lock screen appears. Now it'll say for the time you selected. :)

Hope it helped. A positive vote is always appreciated. :D

Comment: But how do I leave it on for more than 10min? My phone has 10min as the maximum to choose in the Display settings.

Comment: Didnt get that. Could you be more specific about what you wanna say

Comment: @Sarthak The max you can select in the options is 10 minutes. He wants more than 10 minutes (i.e. custom delay).

Comment: Ohkay, my buddy right now there is no such solution from me. Maybe updating your firmware to 4.3 or 4.4 might help. I said this because both of my Samsung Galaxy S4 and Motorola Moto G run on android 4.4.2 and both provide 30 min as maximum. Clearly i don't know about forever on but some devices also give the option to set screen timeout to 'OFF' . Brother I'll let you know the answer as soon as i discover it.

Comment: My lockscreen turns off in a few seconds even though I set it to 10 min!!! I pressed the kockscreen button then pressed again but it still shuts off.

Comment: This doesn't work. The home screen timeout is separate from the lockscreen timeout.

Answer (score 0):

just maybe I've got the answer to your second problem too!

OK so here it is, head over to Google play store (link here- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chemdroid.screentimeouttoggle&hl=en&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Dscreen+timeout+toggle ) and download this app called Screen Timeout Toggle.

Now open the app and tick 'Always Active'. Now the screen will never time out. Now what you must do is lock the device's screen manually by pressing the lock button. Now if you slide down it must say 'screen must stay on'. If it doesn't show that then you must tap on the toggle option. This would make it start. Now lock the screen again and there you have it. It'll never time out.

There's just only one problem, and that is that the developer says that 'Now it works for 4.2 also' . So I'm just not sure that whether it'd work for you as you said that your device is running 4.1 .
If it worked then please let me know.
Positive vie is always encouraged :D

Comment: the lock button is the button on the phone top right-hand side corner right?

Comment: Yes, in Samsung devices it's the one on the top right side :)